# How to detect TMenuItem right click?

Tags: delphi

platform:delphi 2010

1. drop Tmainmenu on form1

   drop Tpopupmenu on form1

   add mainmenu1 and popupmenu items
   (mainmenu --> file -->item1 , popupmenu-->popup item1)

   item1.onRgihtClick show popupmenu

   f9

   file-->item1 right click, popupmenu , select item1 bla bla bla....

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 222
  ClientWidth = 447
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  Menu = MainMenu1
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object MainMenu1: TMainMenu
    Left = 136
    Top = 64
    object file1: TMenuItem
      Caption = 'file'
      object recentfile1: TMenuItem
        Caption = 'item 1'
      end
    end
  end
  object PopupMenu1: TPopupMenu
    Left = 24
    Top = 136
    object popupitem1: TMenuItem
      Caption = 'popup item'
      OnClick = popupitem1Click
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Having a right-click menu for a menu item would be very contrary to any kind of expected behavior of a menu. Why not put the extra menu items in a submenu instead?

Comment: @Michael: Yet this behaviour is common in Microsoft Windows, if the items of the popup menu are files (in some sense). In Windows 7, click Start/Recent. Here you can right-click any menu item and get a new popup menu.

Comment: @Michael Madsen ; mozilla firefox  , internet explorer etc. open the favorities menu , and right click any menu item showing new popup menu(open , open the new window , delete , renema etc..)

Comment: I said it's not expected behavior, not that it's unheard of. There are exceptions to the rule, yes, but nothing in this question suggests that it makes sense for this to be one of them. You don't get right-click options on your MRU list in Word, for example. (No, I'm not counting 2007 and 2010 here, because they're not regular menus - and neither is the start menu, for that matter.)

Comment: I think this is expected. If I could not right-click a file-ish menu item (Recent, Favourites, Start Menu item, Documents, etc.) I would be upset.

Comment: @Andreas: Most of those are part of the Start Menu, but since there is a very distinct difference in appearance between that and a regular menu, the same rules do not necessarily apply; a user can very easily see that this looks different from the normal stuff, and that gives it the privilege of acting a bit different as well. While Favorites are indeed a case of a seemingly normal menu with right-click options, it's an exception to the rule: for plain old menus, this sort of thing is rarely seen outside of browsers, and you usually have other ways of reaching that functionality.

Comment: @Michael: Yes, open Explorer and browse to the file. This is very annoying. Alternatively, enter its path in the Start Menu or in Win+R. In my case, most paths start with "C:\Users\Andreas Rejbrand\Documents\Bla\Bla2\..."

Comment: Please notice that this question probably has been answered at EE: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Pascal/Delphi/Q_20394288.html But as usual, you need to pay to see the solution (or start a trial period).

Comment: @Michael: Favourite menus often have a different appearance compared to all other menus in a browser. At least IE8 has two very distinct types of menus: the normal menu and the right-clickable one.

Comment: @Andreas: No need to pay for EE: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experts-Exchange#Viewing_solutions_without_membership

Comment: @Michael - + 1 for mentioning working examples not being regular menus. *But*, this is a technical question. It can, but does not have to justify its context. IOW, nothing in the question also suggests that it does not make sense for the OP's particular design - it is only a simplified problem presentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the menu structure for the below sample

```
File1           Edit1
  FileItem11      EditItem11
  FileItem21      EditItem21
```

and two popup menu items. The code:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    MainMenu1: TMainMenu;
    File1: TMenuItem;
    FileItem11: TMenuItem;
    FileItem21: TMenuItem;
    Edit1: TMenuItem;
    EditItem11: TMenuItem;
    EditItem21: TMenuItem;
    PopupMenu1: TPopupMenu;
    PopupItem11: TMenuItem;
    PopupItem21: TMenuItem;
    procedure PopupItem11Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure PopupItem21Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FSelectedItem: TMenuItem;
    FTracking: Boolean;
    procedure MenuRButtonUp(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_MENURBUTTONUP;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.MenuRButtonUp(var Msg: TMessage);
var
  Cmd: UINT;
begin
  if not FTracking then
    FSelectedItem :=
        MainMenu1.FindItem(GetMenuItemID(Msg.LParam, Msg.WParam), fkCommand);

  if (not FTracking) and (FSelectedItem <> nil) then begin
    FTracking := True;
    LongBool(Cmd) := TrackPopupMenuEx(PopupMenu1.Handle,
                            TPM_RECURSE or TPM_BOTTOMALIGN or TPM_RETURNCMD,
                            Mouse.CursorPos.X, Mouse.CursorPos.Y, Handle, nil);
    FTracking := False;
    if Cmd <> 0 then
      PopupMenu1.DispatchCommand(Cmd);
  end;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TForm1.PopupItem11Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Caption := 'Popup Item 1 clicked on ' + FSelectedItem.Caption;
end;

procedure TForm1.PopupItem21Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // whatever..
  Caption := 'Popup Item 2 clicked on ' + FSelectedItem.Caption;
end;
```

Comment: -1, for saying that standard menus do not support richt-clicking.  They do.  This is possible via the `WM_MENURBUTTONUP` message, which was introduced for this exact purpose: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647610.aspx.  Do a search through the archives at http://www.deja.com, there are plenty of examples of using `WM_MENURBUTTONUP` in Delphi.

Comment: great job , great code. thank you very much to everyone. p.s. @sertac bey, ilgi ve alakaniz icin size ayri tesekkur ederim :)

Comment: @Remy - Ok, removed what i said.

Comment: Would there be a way to extend this to also handle a right-click on the topmost menu items (File1 and Edit1)?

Comment: @Aladdin - It doesn't look like so. Probably you would need to interfere WM_NCRBUTTONUP, check for a hit test of HTMENU and then call GetMenuBarInfo for each item to find the item which you released the right button on.